# Delete items of database via CLI

Tags: php, database, jdatabase, jtable

I would like to delete some items with state "trashed" via CLI. Is it possible to call the delete-method of JTable from CLI?

Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been awhile since I've done this, but as I recall putting this within doExecute should do what you want.

```
$basePath = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_content';
require_once $basePath.'/models/article.php';
$artmodel = new ContentModelArticle(array('table_path' => $basePath.'/tables'));

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$q = "SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE `state` = '-2'";
$db->setQuery($q);
if( $rows = $db->loadObjectList() ) {
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $this->out('Removing '.$row->title);
        $result = $artmodel->delete($row->id);
    }
}
```

In your case, you're deleting items that are already trashed (state=-2), but for the record, this code won't work unless that's the case.  To delete a record that is NOT trashed, you have to trash it first, using the `->save` method prior to the `->delete` method:

```
$data = array('id' => $row->id,'state'=>'-2');
$result = $artmodel->save($data);
$result = $artmodel->delete($row->id);
```

Comment: I believe your forgot to define `$db` ;)

Comment: fussy, fussy, fussy.....lol